# How to find Orthogonal Projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I am very confused regarding the topic of orthogonal projections, so I will be really thankful if someone could help me.

In my script is written that in order to find the orthogonal projection of a vector onto Space we have to:

> 1. find a Basis of the space
> 2. orthonormalise it
> 3. multiply the vector with the every inner product of the vector and
>      the orthonormlised Basis and we get the orthogonal projection

However, somewhere else there is another formula solving projections like

> 1. from the span we have to make a matrix and find the solution of 
>      $A\cdot A^T=A^T\cdot x$ , we get from here a vector
> 2. the vector we got, we multiply with $A$ and that is the orthogonal
>      projection

and also another way solving this like with the Gremian matrix.

So which way is the right, or are all of them right? Which do I have to use in which case and why do we solve it like this?

Comment: They are all equivalent. Use the one that requires the least work for the data you’ve been given. You left out another useful method: find the orthogonal projection onto the complement of the space and subtract it from the vector. This can often require less work than computing the projection directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one vector $x$, the second method is easier. If you have one space and you want to find a projection of multiple vectors, the first one might be easier because you can precalculate the first two steps.

If you project into a subspace with dimension more than half of the dimension of whole space, it is easier to calculate the rejection to the complement, which is the same.